# Check if a file exists in Android

Tags: java, android, android-file, android-download-manager

Android/Java, API level 12.

I'm trying to check if a .zip file exists in the Downloads folder. If it doesn't exist then I'm downloading it from the internet using `DownloadManager`. For the purposes of testing I'm running my `checkIfFileExists` immediately after the `onReceive` method of the DownloadManager, subject to the download being successful. My issue is that `checkIfFileExists` is returning `false` every time, even after I've just downloaded the file and I've checked manually that it does exist.
The relevant code is below.

```java
    DownloadManager dm;
    long queueid;
    String filename = "myfile.zip", url = "http://myurl/", uriString = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        [...]
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String action = intent.getAction();
                if (DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE.equals(action))
                {
                    DownloadManager.Query req_query = new DownloadManager.Query();
                    req_query.setFilterById(queueid);

                    Cursor c = dm.query(req_query);
                    if (c==null)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "Download not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (c.moveToFirst())
                        {
                            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS);
                            if (DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL==c.getInt(columnIndex))
                            {
                                uriString = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_LOCAL_URI));
                                Toast.makeText(context, "Download finished.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                Toast.makeText(context, uriString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                checkIfFileExists();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE));
    }


    public void onClickDownload(View v) // this method seems to be working with no issues.
    {
        dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, filename);
        queueid = dm.enqueue(request);
    }



    private boolean checkIfFileExists()
    {
        File file = new File(uriString);
        if(file.exists())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I was expecting `if(file.exists())` to evaluate to `true` since the file does exist.

What actually happens is `if(file.exists())` always evaluates as `false`.
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You do not have read access to files in `Downloads/`, other than files your app downloaded there itself, on Android 11 and higher. Please use the Storage Access Framework, or put the ZIP file in the directory obtained by `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`.

Comment: @Commonsware I've tried changing to `onClickDownload(View v){ [...] request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, String.valueOf(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS)), filename); [...] }` and within the checkIfFileExists `File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);` but that doesn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Change your method like this.:

```java
private boolean checkIfFileExists(String zipName /*ex: fileName.zip*/) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), zipName);
    if(file.exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, sorry. I'm still getting "Doesn't exist" on every run.
My new method is below.
```    private boolean checkIfFileExists()
    {        
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), filename);
        if(file.exists())
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Doesn't exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }
    }```

Comment: have you declare permission or granted?? if yes then which android version you've used??

Comment: I'd added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`, `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>` to the Manifest file. I'm using Android 5.1.1 which [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#:~:text=%5BSolution%5D%20Request%20Permissions%20for%20Android%201%20Add%20permissions,on%20access%20to%20sensitive%20user%20information...%20See%20More.) suggests you don't need to request them at runtime.